# サイト内で英語が残っている箇所・日本語がおかしい箇所を見つけたときは？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問, 翻訳

サイト内のUI・ヘルプ・コメント・ダイアログ・etc.で翻訳に問題のある箇所を見つけました。これはどこかに報告するとよいでしょうか？

中には以前日本語だったものもあります。どうしてこのようなことが起きるのでしょうか。

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 英語が残っている・翻訳がおかしい箇所を見つけたときは？

ふたつの方法があります。どちらかを選んでください。

#### 方法1. 翻訳ミスをメタに報告する

英語が残っていたり翻訳がおかしくなっていたりする箇所について、メタでの質問の形で投稿してください。その際、[バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)[翻訳](/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3)の2つのタグを付けてください。

どこでその文章を見かけたのか、URLやスクリーンショットがあると助かります。

この投稿を元に、方法2と同じ方法でコミュニティの誰かがシステムに翻訳を提出することになります。

#### 方法2. Traducirから翻訳を提案する

スタック・オーバーフローの翻訳は、[Traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/) というシステムで管理されています。**コミュニティの誰でもログインでき、翻訳を提案できます。**

- https://ja.traducir.win/

このシステムを使って翻訳が提案されると、その翻訳をレビューする権限をもった別のユーザーが翻訳をレビューします。レビューが通り次第システムに翻訳が提出され、いくらかのタイムラグの後、サイトに翻訳が反映されます。このタイムラグは大きいときで1週間程度です。

2020年現在、[暫定モデレーター](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2692)と Stack Exchange の社員がレビューの権限を持っています。

どう翻訳して良いか不安な場合は、チャットもお試しください！　「翻訳支援」というチャットルームにて翻訳に携わる方たちがラフな会話をしています。

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/

### 前は日本語だったところまで英語になってるのは？

現状、翻訳対象の文章は翻訳前の英文で識別されています。

そのため英語版 Stack Overflow で文章に修正が入ると、既存の翻訳が失われてしまいます。

### 翻訳したい部分が Traducir に載ってないときは？

その部分をメタに報告してください。その部分が Traducir で翻訳できるように設定されていない場合があります。

注意すべきこととして、Traducir での検索では、特殊な文字や大文字小文字に気を付けてください。たとえばリンクになっているところや変数になっているところを跨いだ検索をするときに注意が必要です。

### Traducir でできないこと

Traducir では現在、以下のようなことはできません。ものによっては Traducir を改善すれば解決するものもあります。Traducir の開発自体は https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir で行われているので、興味があればチャレンジしてみてください。

- ある画面の中で使われている string を検索する。
- その string がどこで使われているのか検索する。
- string にその string の文脈を書いたメモを追加する。
- ヘルプセンターの一部の文章など、特殊な場所の string を翻訳する。

### Traducir の仕組み

スタック・オーバーフローの翻訳の大元は、[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) というシステムで管理されています。Traducir は Transifex への翻訳の反映をしやすくするためのインターフェースです。

歴史的経緯：Transifex にはあらかじめ許可されたユーザーしかログインできませんでした。そこでコミュニティの誰もが自由に翻訳に参加できるよう開発されたシステムが、Traducir です。

Traducir で承認された翻訳は Transifex へ反映され、その後サイトに反映されます。また Transifex に追加された string は自動的に Traducir にも追加されます。

---

### モデレーター向け

以下、モデレーター向けのヘルプです。

#### Transifex に参加するには？

Stack Exchange の社員にお願いすることで、Transifex にログインできるようになります。これはモデレーターでなくてもお願いすれば可能ですが、大抵のことは Traducir で済むためほぼ必要は無いでしょう。一方モデレーターは例外的な事象に対応できるよう、なるべくログインできるようにしておいてください。

- Transifex：https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/dashboard/

#### ヘルプページを翻訳するには？

ヘルプページやその他一部のページの string は、Transifex で管理されていません。一部の重要な string は、モデレーターや Stack Exchange の社員でないと変更できないようになっています。メタで必要な議論をした後、コミュニティの意思を反映する形でモデレーターが更新を行ってください。

一部のヘルプページは、Stack Exchange の社員にお願いしないとモデレーターが編集できるようになりません。事前にお願いをし、モデレーターが編集できるよう設定を変更してもらってください。

また、あまり重要そうでないところの string が Transifex/Traducir に無い場合、string の追加漏れが考えられます。[バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)扱いとしてメタや Meta Stack Exchange に string を追加してもらえるよう要望を送ってください。