# サイトを翻訳するための新ツールの提案: Traducir

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, traducir.win

#### Traducir をお試しください！翻訳対象は随時追加されています。

Traducir は https://ja.traducir.win/ から使えます！

- 日本語版の翻訳に興味のある方は誰でもご参加いただけます。スタック・オーバーフロー／Stack Overflow のアカウントでログインできます。
- できれば、**[翻訳ガイドライン](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2583/19110)** をご一読ください。不安があれば[翻訳支援チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)が役に立ちます。英語での質問等は[Traducir.winチャット](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win)をご利用ください。
- 翻訳のレビューアーは現在のところ、暫定モデレーターの @YukiInoue さん、@nekketsuuu さん、@cubick さん、翻訳サポートの @aki が担当しています。
- もちろん、Traducir を使用せずに今まで通りメタに投稿して翻訳を編集する、という流れでも構いません :)
- Traducir は https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir で開発されています。コントリビューションも歓迎です！
- [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/) と比較したい場合、[「サイト内で英語が残っている箇所・日本語がおかしい箇所を見つけたときは？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2160/19110)から使用方法をご確認ください。新しく使い始める場合アカウントの承認が必要ですので、[翻訳支援チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)で ping を飛ばして頂ければと思います。
- **最終和訳は必ずTraducirに残すようにしてください**。TransifexがTraducirにオーバーライドされるからです。

---

> TL; DR
>
> - 新しい翻訳ツール https://ja.traducir.win/ ができました。
> - 現在使っている Transifex から移行するか決めたいので、お試しください。

スタック・オーバーフローは本家 Stack Overflow から派生したサイトであり、当初は英語で書かれた部分が多く残っていました。コミュニティの皆さまのご協力のもと、徐々に日本語に翻訳され、今のように日本語で使えるようになっています。

2018 年 9 月の時点では、翻訳作業は以下の流れで行われています。

1. メタへの投稿や個人での気づきを元に、翻訳が必要な場所を割り出す。
2. 和訳する。
3. 多くの場合、[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/) へ和訳を投稿する。
4. 承認を経て、サイトに翻訳が反映される。

しかし、この Transifex というツールが時々ハードルとなっていました。特に Transifex 用のアカウントを作りメンバーとして承認される必要があったため、初めての方が参加しにくくなっていました。

同じような状況は[他の多言語版 Stack Overflow にもあった](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378)ようで、Stack Overflow の技術者である [@g3rv4 さん](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920295/g3rv4)がスペイン語版 Stack Overflow のコミュニティと共に、Transifex のラッパーとなる新しいツールを開発されました。それが [Traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/) です。

Traducir はもともとスペイン語版 Stack Overflow のために開発されました。その後開発者の方々のご助力により、この度日本語版でも使えるようになったのです！　既に暫定モデレーターの間でいくつか翻訳を試しており、動作は確認済みです。

そこで、コミュニティの皆さまにも Traducir を試して頂き、和訳の投稿先を Transifex からTraducir へ移行するかどうか決めようという話になりました。移行するかどうかは日本語版のコミュニティで自由に決めることができます。最初の一歩は、Traducir を使ってみることです :)

**フィードバックをお待ちしております！**　Traducir の疑問点や長所短所等、どんなご意見でも構いません。コメントや回答としてご投稿くださいませ<(_ _)>

Comment: 個人的には、このツールの素晴らしさは、これによって翻訳が community driven で行えるようになること、だと思ってます。

Answer (score 6):

#### Traducir には無い機能について

Transifex にはあって Traducir には未実装の機能として、以下のものがあると気づきました。

- 類似 string がどう訳されているか一覧表示する機能
- その string の訳の履歴を表示する機能

  - **追記**: [コメント欄でご指摘頂いた](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2750/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B0%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%8F%90%E6%A1%88-traducir?cb=1#comment2405_2751)通り、煩雑ですがデータベースを直接見れば履歴を調べることはできるようです。
- 「詳細情報」、特に「文脈」の欄：ただしこの欄は[今までも使えなかった？](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20086496#20086496)
- 「用語集」と「コメント」：これは今までも特に使われて無い気がします……。用語集は、代わりに [Stack Overflowの専門用語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/19110) が使われています。

これらは今後 Traducir に実装できるのでしょうか？

#### UI について

Transifex よりは UI がごちゃごちゃしていなくて、使い始めやすいなと感じました。使い続けやすいかどうかはまだよく分かりません (私は Transifex も Traducir も長くは使っていないので……)。

#### プッシュ通知について

Traducir では定期的に新しい翻訳が無いか探してブラウザのプッシュ通知を送ってくれる仕組みがあることを知りました。これは便利です。ログイン後、メニュー右上の "My account" -> "My Notifications" から設定ができます。何を通知させるかと、どの頻度で調べるかが自由に選べるようになっています。

Comment: Transifexを含めいくつかの翻訳ツールを使用していますが、「用語集」や「コメント」が利用できると翻訳に自信が無い場合のリファレンスに出来ますし、表記揺れや無駄な編集合戦を減らすことができると思います。

Comment: @cubick さん、私はあまり Transifex を使った翻訳をしていないのですが、「用語集」については、代わりにメタ投稿 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/19110 が使われていたという事情があるようです。

Comment: stringの履歴はデータベースにあるとのことですm_ _m
クエリ：db.traducir.win (instructions on database -> instructions)

Comment: @aki さん、https://db.traducir.win にアクセスするとログイン画面になって ID/pass を要求されるのですが、ここには Stack Exchange アカウントでは入れないのでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、こちらでトライください Username: db@traducir.win Password: letMeInPleeeease

Answer (score 2):

**機能要望**
このツール自体のUIが日本語表記に出来ると、使い方のハードルが下がるのかなと思いました。
(GitHubのソースを覗いた感じだとハードコートされている様子です)

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。しかし残念ながら日本語を含む多言語表記に変更することは難しいようです。ごめんなさい！

Comment: でも、"日英翻訳に協力します！"って人が英語のUIだから使いづらいっていうのもおかしな話ですけどね。

Answer (score 2):

翻訳に少しでも興味があるかたは、ぜひ一度ログインしてみてください (((o(*ﾟ▽ﾟ*)o)))!

ちょっとした Memo ->

- Source Regex フィールドに英語を入力する
  ^ : から始まる全ての strings
  $ : で終わる全ての strings　 
  (?i) は case insensitive です

bounty を例にあげてみると、
(?i)bounty : [bounty や Bounty を含む全ての strings](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%28%3Fi%29bounty)
^(?i)bounty : [bounty or Bounty から始まる全ての strings](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5E%28%3Fi%29bounty)
bounty$ : [bounty で終わる全ての strings](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=bounty%24)

- Translation Regex フィールドに日本語を入力する
  ^ $ (?i) など、同じです

^お礼 : [お礼から始まる全ての strings](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?translationRegex=%5E%E3%81%8A%E7%A4%BC)