# 英語が残っている：コメントを残すときの注釈？

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

お世話になります。
回答へのコメント記入時に出てくるヘルプで、未翻訳文章がありましたのでご報告いたします。
（未翻訳文章が残っていた場合の報告？質問？のヘルプがあると嬉しいなと新参者は思いました）

[image: 回答へのコメント記入時のヘルプ]

Comment: 未翻訳文章が残っていたときのヘルプがもっと見やすい場所にあっても良いというのはおっしゃる通りだと思います。現状このことが明記されているのは[こちらのFAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2160/19110)ですが、検索するかFAQ一覧から探すかでないとこのFAQにはたどり着けません。また、メニューバーにある「ヘルプ」には類似の項目がありません。現状未翻訳の英語はそれに遭遇するユーザーが少ない場合が殆どだと思いますので、mikanさんのようにご指摘くださる方を少しでも増やす導線は確保しておいた方が良さそうです。ご提案ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

該当箇所の翻訳をそれぞれ提案しておきましたので、レビュー後に反映されるまでもう少し待ってください。

なお、未訳部分の報告や質問については今回投稿してもらったような形で大丈夫だと思います。
自分から進んで翻訳の提案を行うこともできますので、以下のメタ投稿や[翻訳](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3)タグの付いた他の投稿も参考にしてください。

[サイトを翻訳するための新ツールの提案: Traducir](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2750/3060)